# IFC BIM tiles implementation for streaming geometries - (open bim components library)

Tags: node.js, three.js

here is my implementation for streaming only bim tile geometries. Not error found in the console and want a confirmation whether it’s well implemented so far since I do not perceive an improvement in loading performance.

library link: https://people.thatopen.com/home

```
export class frag_loader{  
     static streamIFCgeom: StreamedGeometries = {
           assets: [],
           geometries: {},
           globalDataFileId:
            "xxxxxx.ifc-processed-global",
     };

///...
static async initLoading(
ifcLoader: OBC.FragmentIfcLoader,
viewer: OBC.Components,
streamer?: OBC.FragmentIfcStreamConverter,
streamLoader?: OBC.FragmentStreamLoader
){
    const arrBuffer =
      await ifcLoaderService.fetchIFCfile();
    const model = await ifcLoader.load(arrBuffer);
    viewer.scene.get().add(model);
      streamer.onGeometryStreamed.add(
        (geometry) => {
          for (const [
            key,
            value,
          ] of Object.entries(geometry)) {
            if (key === "data") {
              const geometries =
                value as OBC.StreamedGeometries;
              const geometryObj: {
                [id: number]: {
                  boundingBox: {
                    [id: number]: number;
                  };
                  hasHoles: boolean;
                  geometryFile: string;
                };
              } = {};
              for (const [
                id,
                data,
              ] of Object.entries(geometries)) {
                const idNumb = Number(id);
                const bb = data.boundingBox;
                const holes = data.hasHoles;
                const globalDataName =
                  "xxxxx.ifc-processed-geometries";
                // const valueSingle = {
                //   idNumb: {
                //     boundingBox: bb,
                //     hasHoles: holes,
                //     geometryFile: globalDataName,
                //   },
                // };
                frag_loader.streamIFCgeom.geometries[
                  idNumb
                ] = {
                  boundingBox: bb,
                  hasHoles: holes,
                  geometryFile: globalDataName,
                };
              }
            }
          }
          // console.log(
          //   "the geometry",
          //   frag_loader.streamIFCgeom.geometries
          // );
        }
      );
      streamer.onAssetStreamed.add(
        (assets: OBC.StreamedAsset[]) => {
          frag_loader.streamIFCgeom.assets =
            frag_loader.streamIFCgeom.assets.concat(
              assets
            );
        }
      );

      await streamer.streamFromBuffer(arrBuffer);
      streamLoader.url =
        environment.VITE_API_URL + "/";
      await streamLoader.load(
        frag_loader.streamIFCgeom as OBC.StreamLoaderSettings,
        true
      );
      (
        viewer.camera as OBC.OrthoPerspectiveCamera
      ).controls.addEventListener(
        "controlend",
        () => {
          streamLoader.culler.needsUpdate = true;
        }
      );
}
}
```

In my backend endpoint:
http://localhost:3000/xxxx.ifc-processed-global
I'm responding with the following json data:  xxxxxx.ifc-processed.json
[image]
[image]